# Parsing JSON to a Map and Set structure

Tags: scala, json

How do I make these line of codes more scala-ish (shorter?). I still get the Java feeling in it (which I want to stay away from).

```
import scala.collection.mutable
val outstandingUserIds: mutable.LinkedHashSet[String] = mutable.LinkedHashSet[String]()    

val tweetJson = JacksMapper.readValue[Map[String, AnyRef]](body)     
val userObj = tweetJson.get("user")    
tweetJson.get("user").foreach(userObj => {
  userObj.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]].get("id_str").foreach(idStrObj => {
    if (outstandingUserIds.exists(outstandingIdStr => outstandingIdStr.equals(idStrObj))) {
      outstandingUserIds.remove(idStrObj.asInstanceOf[String])
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to inflict this JSON library on yourself, your code could be simplified to:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val outstandingUserIds = mutable.LinkedHashSet[String]()    

val tweetJson = JacksMapper.readValue[Map[String, AnyRef]](body)     
for {
  userObj <- tweetJson.get("user")
  idStrObj <- userObj.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]].get("id_str")
} outstandingUserIds -= idStrObj.asInstanceOf[String]
```

But I would recommend you use a better JSON library. For example, using the library that comes with the Play! framework:

```
(body \ "user" \ "id_str").asOpt[String].foreach {id =>
  outstandingUserIds -= id
}
```

Comment: I'm not developing web-app. I'm developing a little daemon process. Can I use Play for that?

Comment: Yes. Even better, you can just include the Play JSON library. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20475410/1224627).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried it, turned out Play framework uses Scala 2.10, while I'm using Scala 2.11 (I'm getting this error in Eclipse: akka-actor_2.10-2.3.3.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (SpecificScalaVersion(2,10,0,Final)))

Hmm... second thought, maybe I'll just switch back to Scala 2.10....

Answer (score 3):

You usually want to avoid mutable collections in Scala, unless you have a good reason.

```
val outstandingUserIds: Set[String] = ...  // immutable

val userId: Option[String] = tweetJson.get("user")
           .flatMap(userObj => userObj.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]].get("id_str"))
           .map(_.asInstanceOf[String])
userId.foreach(id => outstandingUserIds = outstandingUserIds - id)
```

I wrote the type `Option[AnyRef]` just for clarity here; you probably would not write it in production code.

You can subtract an element from a Set even if it is not present.

The constant casting is quite annoying.  Maybe someone who has experience with such a json library will have better suggestions.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks, it works. My understanding:

(1) userObj.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]].get("id_str") returns an instance of Option[AnyRef], which is a kind of collection. So by using flatMap, we take that AnyRef out of the collection, and put it in the resulting list (that's why we use flatMap).

(2) The outcome of that flatMap, we get a a list of AnyRef ( List[AnyRef] ...)

(3) The outcome of map on that list of AnyRef is a list of String (we type-cast each element in the list).

Hmm..., can we say that List[String] is a subtype of Option[String] ? That's what it seems from this snippet.

Comment: Duh, how do I format I my comment?

Comment: You can't format comments, except for the back ticks to highlight code.

Comment: Option is not really a collection, but a monad. Option.flatMap(f: A => Option[B]) returns an Option that is None if the original Option is None, or if the transformation with `f` returns None.  So you can basically chain transformations (you can chain more than two), and if one transformation goes wrong somewhere, you get None in the end.

Comment: By the way, I realized that since I have a flatMap followed by a map, I should have used a for-comprehension like wingedsubmariner.  A for-comprehension in Scala is just syntactic sugar for sequences of maps and flatMaps (and filters).

Comment: Just to keep a note on my understanding of my code. I think I get it now (I was wondering why we have to use flatMap). So I made a little experiment:

    `val letsSee = tweetJson.get("user")
      .map(userObj => {
        println("I'm in the flatMap func " + userObj)
        val duh = userObj.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]].get("id_str")
        println("====> " + duh)
        duh
      })      
    println("letsSee " + letsSee)`    
 
 gives...
 
 ---------------
    I'm in the flatMap func Map(...)
    ====> Some(336021114)
    letsSee Some(Some(336021114))
    ---------------

Comment: If I replace that call to map with a call to "flatMap", I get:

 ---------------
 I'm in the flatMap func Map(...)
    ====> Some(203424061)
    letsSee Some(203424061)
 ---------------

Comment: Either map(...) or flatMap() returns the an object of the same type as the object on which the method in invoked. In this case, tweetJson.get("user") is an Some(AnyRef). Therefore, the flatMap/map will return an instance of "Some(AnyRef)".

Comment: In either case, duh is an instance of Some(AnyRef). So, if you use "map", you will get Some(Some(AnyRef)). But if you "flatMap", the only element inside the "duh" will be taken out, and will be placed directly inside the Some that is returned by "flatMap"..., hence you get "Some(AnyRef)" as letsSee.
 Ok, I know this is obvious for experienced Scala programmers, but it wasn't clear for me, but now it's clear :D

Comment: And we do need formatting in comment :)